# Mathematica error code 0x00000171

Tags: matrix, warning-messages

I'm getting above error code with a Trap 132 indication when attempting an `ArrayPlot` of a complex 130000 x 2048 matrix.

Using *Mathematica* 9.0.1 with Mac OS 10.10.3 & 16GB RAM

My code worked fine with *Mathematica* 8.0.4 using a sparse matrix of 13000 x 2048.

Any ideas what causes the error?

Comment: I think it would useful if you were to add a screen capture of the error message to your question.

Comment: Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):  
eax: 0x00000004  ebx: 0x00000000  ecx: 0xb001067c  edx: 0x974df8ce  
edi: 0x9c27a0a0  esi: 0x9c259658  ebp: 0xb00106f8  esp: 0xb001067c   
ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000247  eip: 0x974df8ce   cs: 0x0000000b   
ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  
cr2: 0x01700048  

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000171
Trap Number:     132

Comment: Macintosh or hackintosh?

Comment: I asked for a screen capture because I wanted to see the exact form of the message as a clue to its origin. Your comment suggests the message comes for OS X, not _Mathematica_. Did you experience a kernel crash? Or a front-end crash?

Comment: Have you used the `Console` app to examine the system logs?

Comment: - MacBookPro running Mac)S 10.10.3 -not hacked

Comment: -Front end crash;  the entire screen capture was too long for insertion into comment, unable to send.  Above "Thread 1" crash message seems to be the only abnormal indication.  I had copied the screen cap into a pdf.  My code takes about 2.5 hours to run;  will use Console app to examine the sys log per your suggestion next time I abuse my code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is almost certainly an out-of-memory crash.

The underlying issue is that the OS X front-end is a 32-bit program, so has a process memory limit of around 2 GB. It is normal for an attempted allocation beyond that limit to lead to a crash.

A similar size `ArrayPlot` example I tried on my Windows machine (where the front-end is 64-bit) used more than 3 GB of RAM according to Task Manager and `MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd]`.

I should mention that our developer team is very aware of this limitation and is working on front-end modernization/creating a full 64-bit Cocoa-based port for OS X. That is not, however, a small project by any means.

Comment: Yep, I've been waiting for years to see this [thing](http://media.salon.com/2012/01/3.png) go away.  That is the really old Carbon (pre Mac OS X!) indication that the app isn't paying attention to you because it's busy, which I still see all the time in the front end.

Comment: ilian: Thanks for this explanation. -stqnt

Comment: Can't wait for the 64-bit Mac front end ... I am really really hoping to see it in 11.3 ... I can no longer export some of my notebooks (e.g. IGraph/M documentation) to PDF due to out-of-memory crashes :|

Comment: Not for 11.3 as far as I know,  but hopefully in the not too distant future.